# CDN support on abp 4 framework

Tags: abp

I'm investigating how to add a CDN network in an abp web application. I found this issue [#294](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/294) dated Jun'18 for consideration in the next versions.

I'm currently working on abp v4.1 and I cannot find any solution to add a CDN.
Have you implemented CDN on a abp framework application? what approach have you used?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why this question has negative points to improve it in the future, could you explain your action?. Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? i have not by the way marked this as a negative but i can see your question needs to be a little more focused and with some more detail fleshed out.  good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I am using a simple setup for CDN where I [send all traffic through cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708-Changing-your-domain-nameservers-to-Cloudflare) and have configured [page rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-Customizing-Cloudflare-s-cache) to cache all images. As a bonus cloudflare also provides free ssl.